# converting bi-monthly Julian days to date in raster image

Tags: r

I have few raster images that represents bi-monthly data. I want to convert bi-monthly into monthly data taking averages of the two images.

There are total of 23 image (single band or single layer)If i stack the image using stack() from list.files, for some reason it reads 46 layers, but if i open all raster images using raster function individually and then stack it reads 23 layers only.

I open image individually and then stacked it, but while i convert the bi-monthly julian days it cannot read correctly after 4th month.

```
library(raster)
setwd("F:/LANDSAT-NDVI/testAverage")
x1<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000001.tif")
x2<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000017.tif")
x3<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000033.tif")
x4<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000049.tif")
x5<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000065.tif")
x6<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000081.tif")
x7<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000097.tif")
x8<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000113.tif")
x9<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000129.tif")
x10<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000145.tif")
x11<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000161.tif")
x12<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000177.tif")
x13<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000193.tif")
x14<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000209.tif")
x15<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000225.tif")
x16<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000241.tif")
x17<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000257.tif")
x18<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000273.tif")
x19<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000289.tif")
x20<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000305.tif")
x21<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000321.tif")
x22<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000337.tif")
x23<-raster("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000353.tif")

data<stack(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20,x21,x22,x23)

julday <-c("landsatNDVISC05SLC2000001.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000017.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000033.tif",
         "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000049.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000065.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000081.tif",
         "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000097.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000113.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000129.tif",
         "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000145.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000161.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000177.tif",
         "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000193.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000209.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000225.tif",
         "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000241.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000257.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000273.tif",
         "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000289.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000305.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000321.tif",
         "landsatNDVISC05SLC2000337.tif","landsatNDVISC05SLC2000353.tif")

julday <- as.numeric(substr(julday, 24,26)) #24 to 26th digit in the file name represents Julian days#

dates <- as.Date(julday, origin=as.Date("2000-01-01"))

combinddat <- setZ(data, dates) 

monthly <- zApply(combinddat, by = format(dates,"%Y-%m"), fun = mean, na.rm = T)
```

The dates produced using that data is wrong; result is as follows

```
> dates
 [1] "2000-01-02" "2000-01-18" "2000-02-03" "2000-02-19" "2000-03-06"
 [6] "2000-03-22" "2000-04-07" "2000-01-14" "2000-01-30" "2000-02-15"
[11] "2000-03-02" "2000-03-18" "2000-04-03" "2000-01-10" "2000-01-26"
[16] "2000-02-11" "2000-02-27" "2000-03-14" "2000-03-30" "2000-01-06"
[21] "2000-01-22" "2000-02-07" "2000-02-23"
```

But i want the dates to be 12 months based on my julian days.

Comment: `dates <- as.Date(substr(julday, 19, 25), format = '%Y%j')`

Comment: Thanks Alistaire, i though the last digit was 26th thats why i was getting wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question but you probably could improve your code a lot with:

```
setwd("F:/LANDSAT-NDVI/testAverage")
library(raster)
f <- list.files(pattern="\\.tif$")
f <- sort(f)
data <- stack(f)
```

Comment: Thanks Robert Hijmans for the cleaner code, but I did not understand why if i use list.files 23 layers becomes 46, but if i read individually using raster(), then it reads 23